# Is there a way to document the composition of an object required in a POST request using Django Rest Swagger?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-swagger

Let's say I have an endpoint for creating `Player` that requires a `Team` object:

### models.py

```
class Team(Model):
    name = CharField()

class Player(Model):
    name = CharField()
    team = ForeignKey(Team)
```

And I have a ModelViewSet as follows:

### views.py

```
class PlayerViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = Player
    serializer = PlayerSerializer
```

### serializers.py

```
class TeamSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = "__all__"

class PlayerSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = "__all__"
```

When I look at my Django Rest Swagger, the "Example value" for data I need to `POST` to create a player looks like:

```
{
    "name": "string",
    "team": {}
}
```

What I want is for the `{}` to be expanded, to show that I would need to provide a `{"name": "string"}` object to create the `Team` object. I've tried adding

`team = TeamSerializer(help_text="{'name': 'string'}")`

to the `PlayerSerializer` but that only adds the data to the `Model` tab on Django Rest Swagger. Is there a way to add this documentation automatically to the `Example` tab and `Model` showing the required `POST` data?

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? Kindly guide us!!